# Import remote variable via ssh

Tags: linux, bash, shell, variables, ssh

I try to import variables of a remote bash script via ssh.

Remote file comlink.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

test=1
new=2
ready=1
```

Local file:

```html
#!/bin/bash

ssh pi@[myIP] "cat /home/pi/comlink.sh"

echo $ready
```

But the variable has no value. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are absolutely certain you can trust the content of that file,
then you can use `eval` to execute its content in the current shell,
thereby "importing" those variables:

```
eval "$(ssh pi@[myIP] "cat /home/pi/comlink.sh")"
```

Comment: Yes - the content can be trusted. I know exactly which variables are stored. And this solution works like a charm. Thank you!